# SQL/C# DateTime into Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

i want to make javascript countdown which takes SQL server DateTime as endtime and C# datetime as time which i will substract from SQL server endtime here is code

```
            <script>

            var EndTime = @Context.Session.GetString("EndTime");

            var nowtime = @DateTime.Now.ToString();

            var difference = EndTime - nowtime;

            var initialTime = difference ;

            var seconds = initialTime;
            function timer() {
                var days = Math.floor(seconds / 24 / 60 / 60);
                var hoursLeft = Math.floor((seconds) - (days * 86400));
                var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
                var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
                var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
                var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
                if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
                }
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + "dias " + hours + "horas " + minutes + "minutos " + remainingSeconds + "segundos";
                if (seconds == 0) {
                    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
                } else {
                    seconds--;
                }
            }
            var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);

        </script>


<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```

`@Context.Session.GetString("EndTime")`  this is datetime from SQL server

adding datetimes this way to Javascript is not working need some help  THX.

Comment: Just a quick suggestion; you should consider using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for datetime manipulations in javascript.

Comment: Honestly i had it done without that in 1 line code some how but lost file and cant remember :(

Comment: Can you provide more information by putting ```console.log(EndTime)``` and ```console.log(nowtime)``` and by showing the outputs of them, so that we can figure out what we are dealing with.

Comment: Need some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>

<script>


            var t1 = "@Context.Session.GetString("EndTime")";
            var endTime = new Date(t1);

            var t2 = "@DateTime.Now.ToString()";
            var nowTime = new Date(t2);

            var initialTime = (endTime - nowTime)/1000;

            var seconds = initialTime;
            function timer() {
                var days = Math.floor(seconds / 24 / 60 / 60);
                var hoursLeft = Math.floor((seconds) - (days * 86400));
                var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
                var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
                var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
                var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
                if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
                }
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + "dias " + hours + "horas " + minutes + "minutos " + remainingSeconds + "segundos";
                if (seconds == 0) {
                    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
                } else {
                    seconds--;
                }
            }
            var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);

        </script>
```

I remembered how i had it done  this works in my case  THX all.